# qtip2 position getting changed after close

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, qtip2

I am implementing the qtip2 with fullcalendar jquery plugin. Both are great plugins . But I have problem with qtip positioning. I am using the below code.

```
$(window).load(function() { 
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();     

        var tooltip = $('<div/>').qtip({
            id: 'calendar',
            prerender: true,
            overwrite: false, 
            content: {
                text: ' ',
                title: {
                    button: true
                }
            },
            position: {
                my: 'bottom center',
                at: 'top center',
                target: 'mouse',
                viewport: $(window),
                adjust: {
                    mouse: false,
                    scroll: false
                }
            },
            events: {
                hide: function(event, api) {
                    alert('test');
                     //$(this).qtip("destroy");
                }
            },
            show: false,
            hide: false,
            style: 'qtip-light'
        }).qtip('api');


        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            eventClick: function(data, event, view) {
                var content = '<h3>'+data.title+'</h3>' + 
                    '<p><b>Start:</b> '+data.start+'<br />' + 
                    (data.end && '<p><b>End:</b> '+data.end+'</p>' || '');

                tooltip.set({
                    'content.text': content
                })
                .reposition(event).show(event);
            },
            dayClick: function() { tooltip.hide() },
            eventResizeStart: function() { tooltip.hide() },
            eventDragStart: function() { tooltip.hide() },
            viewDisplay: function() { tooltip.hide() },
            events: [
                        {
                            title: 'All Day Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Long Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                            end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                        },
                        {
                            id: 999,
                            title: 'Repeating Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            id: 999,
                            title: 'Repeating Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Meeting',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Lunch',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                            end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Birthday Party',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                            end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Click for Google',
                            start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                            end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                            url: 'http://google.com/'
                        }
                    ]       
        }); 

    });
```

This is working fine for the first time. I mean when I click on any of event name qtip pop is showing correctly after that  if I click inside the popup window or press the close button of the popup window and again click on the event name the position of tool tip got changed . It is not displaying on the correct position with event name .[image: Second Screen].

**Second Screen**(After closing previous popup and clicking on event name )
[image: Intial Screen]

Please suggest me a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the reposition() function in qTip2 version 2.1.1. If you use version 2.2.0 it works as expected.

http://qtip2.com/v/stable/jquery.qtip.js

http://qtip2.com/v/stable/jquery.qtip.css

Answer (score 0):

It work´s for me, with 2.2.0 version:

position: {
  ...,
  at: ' ',
  ...
},

tooltip.set({
  ...,
  'position.at': 'top center'
})